# How to configure network using docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I'm using this docker image https://github.com/moodlehq/moodle-docker and it works as advertised. Among other things it exposes web server on localhost:8000 address. What I would like is to bind it to the host's ip instead.

Using raw docker something like that is accomplished with

```
docker run --network=host [container]
```

What should be placed in the yml file for docker-compose as documentation is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Standard practice is to have the server inside the container bind to 0.0.0.0, and use the `docker run -p` option to publish a port on the host.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `network_mode` in compose files -

`network_mode: "host"`

Sample compose -

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    image: 'node:6-alpine'
    network_mode: host
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=production
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode